# periodically check for the opening of a tab

Tags: jquery, google-chrome-extension

I have set my website as google chrome extension.Presently what happens is that,when i click on the extension icon it navigates to my website's home page. Now what I need is that,when I install the extension,at that moment(ie,when the extension becomes active) itself,it has to check whether my website's page is already opened in any other tabs.If it is not opened then create a new tab.If it is opened,then it has to perform all the functions automatically just like it performs when i click on the extension icon.
Here is my background.js

```
     function getGmailUrl() {
     return "http://calpinemate.com/";
     }
     function isGmailUrl(url) {
     return url.indexOf(getGmailUrl()) == 0;
     }
     chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(gotopage);

     function gotopage(){    
     chrome.tabs.query({
      url: "http://calpinemate.com/*",
      currentWindow: true
      }, function(tabs) {
      if (tabs.length > 0) {
        var tab = tabs[0];
        console.log("Found (at least one) Gmail tab: " + tab.url);
        console.log("Focusing and refreshing count...");
        chrome.tabs.update(tab.id, { active: true });
         updateIcon();
     } else {
        console.log("Could not find Gmail tab. Creating one...");
        chrome.tabs.create({ url: getGmailUrl() });
         updateIcon();
     } 
     });
    }

   if (chrome.runtime && chrome.runtime.onStartup) {
   chrome.runtime.onStartup.addListener(function() {
   updateIcon();
   });
   } else {
   chrome.windows.onCreated.addListener(function() {
   updateIcon();
   });
  }
  function updateIcon(){

  var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
  req.addEventListener("readystatechange", function() {
  if (req.readyState == 4) {
    if (req.status == 200) {
        localStorage.item=req.responseText;

        if(localStorage.item==1){
          chrome.browserAction.setIcon({path:"calpine_logged_in.png"});
          chrome.browserAction.setBadgeBackgroundColor({color:[190, 190, 190, 230]});
          chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText({text:""});   
        }
        else{
        chrome.browserAction.setIcon({path:"calpine_not_logged_in.png"});
        chrome.browserAction.setBadgeBackgroundColor({color:[190, 190, 190, 230]});
        chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText({text:""}); 
        }

    } else {
        // Handle the error
        alert("ERROR: status code " + req.status);
    }
    }
   });
   req.open("GET", "http://blog.calpinetech.com/test/index.php", true);
   req.send(null);
   }
```

here what is happening is that when i activate my extension,there appears an  icon near address bar.when i click on that icon,the updateIcon() is called and it reads one of the server file named index.php and retrieves the output of index.php and according to that output,the color of the icon is set.Now what I need is that,without clicking on the icon itself,(ie,when the extension is activated) all the above functions should be performed periodically.That means when the extension is active it should check for if any tabs are opened for my website and if so,it has to change the icon color accordingly.Please anyone help me.How can I do it?

this is my manifest.json

```
{
"name": "Calpine Extension",
"version": "1.0",
"description": "Log on to calpinemate",
"manifest_version": 2,
"browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon_128.png"
},
"background": {
    "persistent": false,
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
},

"browser_action": {
    "default_title": "Test Extension",
    "default_icon": "calpine_not_logged_in.png"
},
"permissions": [

  "*://blog.calpinetech.com/test/index.php",
   "alarms",
   "notifications"
  ]

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

HI I got the answer myself..

chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(updateIcon); has to be called before   chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(gotopage);